# ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I went through this link: [Docker push - net/http: TLS handshake timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070528/docker-push-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout), but it did not solved my issue. I am simply running the https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics using the `docker-compose up` command.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for sqshq/piggymetrics-mongodb:latest
Pulling rabbitmq (rabbitmq:3-management)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
[root@ech-10-1XXX PiggyMetrics]#
[root@ech-10-1XXX PiggyMetrics]# docker-compose up
Pulling rabbitmq (rabbitmq:3-management)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/rabbitmq/manifests/3-management: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Frabbitmq%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Deployed and run the code on

> uname -a
>
> Linux ech-10-XXXX 4.1.12-61.1.18.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Nov 4 15:48:30 PDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Looks like a Network problem

Comment: oh ok,  may be you're right. Will try after sometime

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was facing the same error `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: TLS handshake timeout` because of **slow internet** connection.

Switching to a comparatively **faster internet** connection didn't fix my problem at first. Then I **restarted** docker and it worked.

```sh
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: In windows 10 go to the docker icon on lower-left corner of window. Right click on docker and second last option is restart the docker. TADA!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me like a charm. but damn! why do we have to restart for real? I hope Docker newer version fixes this.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f

Answer (score 5):

The reason is the network policy in my area.You can change your mirror address and try, in my cases, I changed the mirror address and works.I am using macOS Catalina:

```
"registry-mirrors" : [
    "https://dockerhub.azk8s.cn"
  ]
```

Hope this help you.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Put **debug: true** under the docker-engine tab and restart the docker. This worked for me on **MAC M1**.[image]

Answer (score 3):

This most of the times happens when my internet connection is slow. Please check your internet connection and retry.

Comment: Run into the same issue while downloading a docker image with size 600Mb. It looks like my internet was slow and I had to switch to fast internet to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Try switching your internet connection.
If you are connected via WiFi try connecting with LAN.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. It was fixed by **resetting demon settings** on Docker Desktop macOS Catalina. I hope It will work for you .

*Possible Solutions*

1. Check internet speed and connect to **Faster Internet**
2. **Restart Docker**
3. **Reset Demon Settings**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there is an entry in the `/etc/hosts` which needs to be removed as  it was pointing to wrong docker.io entry always.

Its silly though, took sometime to figure out it.

Answer (score 0):

If your region is restricted by the Docker server's use proxy.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, try restarting the docker daemon.

Then log in with your docker Id `docker login` in your terminal...

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On rhel, try

```
# docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. 
If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx

WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

It works fine.

sometimes you can pull a lot of images, normally you can pull 200 images for free every 6 hours
Don't ask me why this connection,
I think docker needs a connection for that.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps Worked for me on mac Ventura 13.1:

Clean / Purge data — from Docker Dashboard
Reset to factory defaults — From docker dashboard
Restart Docker Desktop — from docker dashboard

Comment: Why would this work? Please add more details - otherwise this is a "turn it off and on again" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens. I also faced this issue. I just reloaded the daemon and restarted the docker service. It solved this issue. You can use the below commands.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

.

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

.

```
docker pull hello-world
```

Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world